# Verify Sherman–Morrison–Woodbury rank-one update inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, rank-1-matrices

> Given $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ non-singular and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $\overline{A} = A + ab^T$. If $\overline{A}$ is nonsingular then show that:
>
> \begin{gather*}
>    \overline{A}^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{A^{-1} ab^T A^{-1}}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \tag{A.27} \\
> \end{gather*}

Attempt to alebraically show that $\overline{A} \cdot \overline{A}^{-1} = I$:

\begin{gather*}
  \overline{A} \cdot \overline{A}^{-1} = (A + ab^T) A^{-1}
  - (A + ab^T) \frac{A^{-1} ab^T A^{-1}}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \\
  = I + a b^T A^{-1} - \frac{ab^T A^{-1} + (ab^T A^{-1})^2}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \\
  = I + a b^T A^{-1} - \frac{ab^T A^{-1} (I + ab^T A^{-1})}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \\
  = \left(I + \frac{1}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} ab^T A^{-1} \right) (I + ab^T A^{-1}) \\
  % = \frac{(1 + b^TA^{-1}a) (I + a b^T A^{-1}) - ab^T A^{-1} (I + ab^T A^{-1})}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \\
  % = \frac{(I + b^TA^{-1}a I - ab^T A^{-1}) (I + a b^T A^{-1})}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \\
\end{gather*}

from here, I'm stuck. The algebra isn't giving me $I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the key is to note that $$ab^T A^{-1} + ab^T A^{-1}ab^TA^{-1} = a(1 + b^TA^{-1}a)b^TA^{-1}$$ so then you get
\begin{align*}
  \overline{A} \cdot \overline{A}^{-1} &= (A + ab^T) A^{-1}
  - (A + ab^T) \frac{A^{-1} ab^T A^{-1}}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \\
  &= I + a b^T A^{-1} - \frac{ab^T A^{-1} + ab^T A^{-1}ab^TA^{-1}}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a} \\
&= I + ab^TA^{-1} - \frac{a(1 + b^TA^{-1}a)b^TA^{-1}}{1 + b^TA^{-1}a}
\end{align*}
And then you are done since the quantity $(1 + b^TA^{-1}a)$ is just a scalar.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!!